# Why do we define the modulus of a complex number as we do?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

For a complex number $z = a+bi$, we say that its modulus is: $$|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

When we draw complex numbers in the Argand diagram, intuitively, this makes sense.
But if we used a different projection for the diagram (i.e. a different metric for distance) then it wouldn't necessarily. Of course, complex numbers can also be written as:

$$z = re^{i\theta} = r(\cos\theta +i\sin\theta)$$

so an equivalent question could be, if this is what we define, *why* we define that:

$$|e^{i\theta}| = |\cos\theta + i\sin\theta| = 1$$

for all values of $\theta$, rather than just $\theta = n\pi$.

The answer may simply be that it is convenient to work with this definition. But is there a deeper reason? Are there any problems for which it is convenient to define things differently? And what would be the consequences if we did things differently?

Comment: Definitions are almost always made because something is used repeatedly and is worth defining. This is one such example.

Comment: It seems quite natural to define the magnitude (or "norm") of a complex number $z$ to be the distance from $z$ to the origin, and Euclidean distance is probably the most intuitive way of measuring distance. One nice thing about this definition of the norm of $z$ is that norms are multiplicative: $\| z_1 z_2 \| = \| z_1 \| \| z_2 \|$.

Comment: For power series, we have that the series has a radius of convergence $R$ such that the series converges for $|z|<R$ and diverges for |z|>R.$ That wouldn’t work with another metric.

Comment: Have you not studied vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I have. It is not immediately clear to me why we should treat $\Bbb C$ as being isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$. We certainly can do, but my question was why. Noah's answer gives excellent justification.

Comment: @legionwhale Because if we interpret the real and imaginary parts as $x$ and $y$ coordinates, then complex multiplication corresponds to rotation/scaling.

Comment: I suppose one could use $|z| = a$ if they wanted to keep it real. ;)

Comment: An example of this pls i didnt quite get it : "different projection for the diagram (i.e. a different metric for distance) then it wouldn't necessarily. " @legionwhale

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As CyclotomicField points out, it is a very convenient definition: regardless of whether we give it a name, the map $(a+bi)\mapsto \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ comes up frequently.

However, we can indeed give an "intrinsic" motivation: there are a few basic assumptions which, when combined, identify the standard definition of modulus uniquely.

- First, we have a "positivity" axiom: we want $\vert x\vert\ge 0$ for all $x$ and we want $\vert x\vert=0$ iff $x=0$.
- Next, we have an "algebraic" axiom: thinking of a complex number as a unit vector scaled by a number (its modulus), we want the modulus function to be multiplicative: $\vert x\vert\vert y\vert$ should equal $\vert xy\vert$. Moreover, (real) scalar multiplication should play with the norm in the obvious way: $\vert \alpha x\vert=\vert\alpha\vert\vert x\vert$ (where the first "$\vert\cdot\vert$" refers to the usual absolute value function on $\mathbb{R}$); if you like, you can think of this as saying that the complex modulus should agree with the real modulus on real numbers.
- Finally, we have a "topological" axiom: we want the map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\vert x\vert$ to be continuous.

This turns out to be enough to identify the standard modulus function! The positivity and algebraic axioms alone tell us that $\vert 1\vert=1$ (since it must be nonzero yet equal to its square), and in turn that $\vert -1\vert=1$ (since it must be a nonnegative square root of $\vert 1\vert=1$), and in turn that $\vert i\vert=1$ (since it must be a nonnegative square root of $\vert-1\vert=1$), and so forth. In fact, this shows that $\vert e^{i\theta}\vert=1$ whenever $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$. And then the topological axiom finishes things off: by continuity we must have $\vert e^{i\theta}\vert=1$ for **every** $\theta$, and thinking about scalar multiplication pins down the value of $\vert x\vert$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Out of curiosity, when does the map to $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ come up? Personally, I have only used it to calculate the moduli of complex numbers (or distances in $R^2$), so (from what little experience I have) that alone as justification would beg the question. Your answer is enlightening - thank you.

Comment: It is the hypotenuse of a right triangle. @legionwhale It is often referred ro as the Euclidean norm, because it is the basis of Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Hi! You missed one very important point, namely the **triangle inequality**. Do you mind adding it to your point list? =)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but as I say that begs the question. That only comes up if you make the choice to use Euclidean geometry. The rest of the reasoning in the answer explains why we make this choice very well, but otherwise, when would the map $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ come up? As far as I can see, the map comes up as a consequence of choosing this modulus function, not the other way around.

Comment: @user21820 I didn't add it since it's not necessary: I wanted to use as small a set of assumptions as possible. and we don't actually need the triangle inequality for that.

Comment: One wonders how you define continuity of a function $\Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{R}$ without referring to the absolute value on $\Bbb{C}$ itself.

Comment: @mechanodroid $\mathbb{C}$ inherits the product topology from $\mathbb{R}$ via the bijection $(a,b)\mapsto a+bi$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Okay I see your point! Is there an alternative minimal list of nice axioms that does include the triangle inequality and also uniquely identifies the euclidean norm as a natural norm for $ℂ$?

Comment: @mechanodroid: And for $ℝ$, the topology does not need the absolute value as you only need the linear ordering to define neighbourhoods.

Comment: @user21820 Re: your second comment, in fact just the algebraic structure is enough to get the ordering, and hence the topology, since $a\le b$ iff $\exists x(x^2+a=b)$. Re: your first comment, I don't immediately see one offhand but that doesn't mean that one doesn't exist (I *think* I got the right number of negatives there).

Comment: @user21820 Actually, re: your first comment see KCd's answer!

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Oh oops I didn't realize KCd posted an answer after my earlier comment and I didn't see it when I came back here. Sorry about that, and thanks! =)

Comment: @user21820 I didn't see it either, nor did I think about that argument, simple though it is!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Of course, thank you. Do you perhaps know if the same holds for $\Bbb{Q}$? Meaning $|\cdot| : \Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{R}$ is (algebraically) continuous, nonnegative and multiplicative, then it is the usual absolute value. If you also stipulate triangle inequality, then the result should follow from Ostrowski's theorem, I think.

Comment: @mechanodroid the term "(algebraically) continuous" doesn't mean anything. You need to *specify a topology first* on $\mathbf Q$ before you can ask if a function on $\mathbf Q$ is continuous.  Every absolute value on a field $F$ is a continuous function $F \to \mathbf R$ when you use the topology on $F$ coming from the metric defined by that absolute value.  Similarly, a metric $d \colon X \times X \to \mathbf R$ on a set $X$ is always continuous using the topology on $X$ defined by the metric.  But you can't ask if a function on a set is continuous when you don't indicate a topology.

Comment: @KCd I know, I was referring to the standard topology on $\Bbb{Q}$ defined by the basis of intervals $\langle a,b\rangle = \{x \in \Bbb{Q} : a < x < b\}$ where the ordering on $\Bbb{Q}$ is defined algebraically as $x < y$ if $(\exists z \in \Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\})(a+z^2=b)$. Noah Schweber pointed out in a comment that the standard ordering on $\Bbb{Q}$ can be characterized purely algebraically, hence i emphasized "algebraically" continuous precisely to specify a topology.

Comment: Finally I understand why I wasn't entirely satisfied with this answer (and KCd's as well). It is explained [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4976/113769) that if we somehow start with the field $\Bbb{C}$, we cannot uniquely define or find $\Bbb{R}$ inside it only by using language of field theory. Specifying a copy $\Bbb{R} \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ equips $\Bbb{C}$ with additional structure. Hence an "absolute value on $\Bbb{C}$ which extends the standard absolute value on $\Bbb{R}$" doesn't make sense purely in the language of field theory.

Comment: @mechanodroid but if you want to talk about absolute value functions at all you need to go beyond the language of field theory to even get started, since absolute value functions take values in $\mathbb{R}$. So I don't buy that objection in this context.

Comment: I disagree, define fields $\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{C}$ separately. We are looking at the function $|\cdot|:\Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{R}$ satisfying properties purely in the language of field theory. As you said, the order in $\Bbb{R}$ is defined algebraically. The copy $\Bbb{R}_{\Bbb{C}}$ you find in $\Bbb{C}$ isn't the same as $\Bbb{R}$ which is the codomain. Anyway, maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Don't take this as negative criticism of your answer, I'm merely trying to understand how to correctly formulate the original question and what to expect of its possible answers.

Comment: "We are looking at the function [stuff] satisfying properties purely in the language of field theory." That's news to me. **Why** are we interested in the language of field theory specifically? That language isn't enough to discuss topological aspects of $\mathbb{C}$ either, or talk about the metric. And in the language of "two separate fields," **no** interesting map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is definable at all. I don't understand why the language of fields (or its simple variants) is the right language to focus on here, it seems extremely **un**natural to me.

Answer (score 31):

Do you like the absolute value on $\mathbf R$?  Well, it turns out that the formula $|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the *unique* absolute value on $\mathbf C$ extending the absolute value on $\mathbf R$. That is not why it was originally defined, but it provides an excellent reason that this function plays such a prominent role in work on the complex numbers. You don't need anything like polar decomposition ($re^{i\theta}$) to prove that uniqueness. It follows from $\mathbf R$ being complete and $\mathbf C$ being finite-dimensional over $\mathbf R$.

An "absolute value" on a field $F$ is an $\mathbf R$-valued function $|x|$ for $x \in F$ such that (i) $|x| \geq 0$ with equality if and only if $x = 0$, (ii), $|xy| = |x||y|$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $F$, and (iii) $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $F$.  Using an absolute value on $F$ we get a metric on $F$ by $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ and that leads to associated topological and analytic ideas on $F$ if it has some nice properties for this metric (complete, locally compact, and so on).

You can apply this concept to a division ring in place of a field.  In that spirit, the absolute value on quaternions, given by $|a+bi+cj+dk| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}$, is the unique absolute value on the quaternions that extends the absolute value on $\mathbf R$.

Comment: +1. Note to the OP that, in my opinion at least, this is a **strictly better** axiomatization than the one I describe in the sense of mathematical utility; I picked my set of axioms for purely expository reasons.

Comment: Do you perhaps know how to describe *all* possible absolute values on $\Bbb{C}$, not necessarily extending the standard absolute value on $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @mechanodroid there is no reasonable answer to that question: for every field extension $L/K$, an absolute value on $K$ always extends (using Zorn's lemma) to an absolute value on $L$.   It is like asking for a description of all possible bases of $\mathbf R$ as a $\mathbf Q$-vector space.

Comment: That said, one could hope for a classification of "tame" absolute values, e.g. ones which are Borel with respect to the usual topologies on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (and set theory provides even richer notions of "tameness"). This is often highly restrictive, though - for example, in a precise sense $\mathbb{R}$ has **no** "tame" (Hamel) bases as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space whatsoever. (@mechanodroid)

Comment: It's highly restrictive, as you suggested. An absolute value on the nonzero numbers of $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$ is a homomorphism $\mathbf R^\times \to (0,\infty)$ or $\mathbf C^\times \to (0,\infty)$ with extra properties, and a measurable homomorphism of locally compact groups is continuous (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120738/is-a-measurable-homomorphism-on-a-lie-group-smooth). So the only absolute values on $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf C$ are powers of the standard absolute values.

Comment: How do you know that it's "the unique absolute value..."? Did you show that and I'm missing it, or is that just commonly known?

Comment: @Joe  I did *not* show the uniqueness. It is a consequence of the completeness of $\mathbf R$ and finite-dimensionality of $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf H$ as real vector spaces. There is a general theorem that if $K$ is a field *complete* with respect to an absolute value $|\cdot|$ and $L$ is a finite extension field of $K$ then $|\cdot|$ has a unique extension to an absolute value on $L$. (The proof also works if $L$ is a division ring rather than a field.) This is proved in books on $p$-adic analysis (e.g., the book by Gouvea), where there are *lots* of finite extensions of complete fields.

Comment: @Joe if $|\cdot|$ is an absolute value on a field $K$ and $L$ is a finite extension field of $K$ then $|\cdot|$ has an extension to an absolute value on $L$ (and at most $[L:K]$ extensions) but it might have more than one if $K$ is not complete with respect to $|\cdot|$. For example, the usual absolute value on $\mathbf Q$ has two extensions to an absolute value on $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$.